# Python modules to plot game of life script

Tags: python, matplotlib, conways-game-of-life

I wanted to know what the modules you recommend for plotting lists of coordinates on the X-Y plane are. The purpose is to implement Game of Life; I've tried  matplotlib.pyplot but I've got some issues with axes ratio and in general it doesn't seem like the best way to plot some sort of animation. The main idea in the script is to plot the world in which the cells live, with a tick given from time.sleep.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Cell:
    #Cell class, with coordinates and an ON-OFF state
    def __init__(self,x=0,y=0,state=0):
        self.state=state
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.coord=[self.x,self.y]
    def __repr__(self):
        if self.state:      
            return "*"
        else:
            return " "
    #methods to turn on and off the cells:
    def turn_on(self):
        self.state=1
        return self
    def turn_off(self):
        self.state=0
        return self

class Mondo:
    #the world in which the cells live:
    def __init__(self,width=10,height=30,starting_cells=[]):
        self.width=width
        self.height=height
        self.grid=[[Cell(i,j) for j in range(height)] for i in range(width)]
        for cell in starting_cells:
            self.grid[cell.x][cell.y]=cell

    def __repr__(self):
    #this method is needed just if I wanted to use just the print statement instead of matplotlib
        return "_"*(2*self.height+3)+"\n"+"\n".join([" ".join(["|"]+[" "+str(cell)+" " for cell in self.grid[row]]+["|"]) for row in range(self.width)])+"\n"+"_"*(2*self.height+3)
    def plotlib(self):
        #this is the best I can do:
        Xaxis=[cell.x for i in range(self.width) for cell in self.grid[i] if    cell.state]
        Yaxis=[cell.y for i in range(self.width) for cell in self.grid[i] if cell.state]
        plt.axis([0,self.width, 0, self.height])
        return plt.show(plt.scatter(Xaxis,Yaxis,c="000000", marker='s'))

    def __getitem__(self,row):
        return self.grid[row]

    def pos_cell(self,coord):
        #retrieves the cell given the coordinates
        return self.grid[coord[0]][coord[1]]
    def cell_state(self,coord):
        #outputs the cell's state on given coord
        return self.pos_cell(coord).state
    def neighbors_state(self,coord,cont=0):
        #sums the neghbors' cell state
        cell=self.pos_cell(coord)
        x,y=cell.x,cell.y
        for hor in [-1,0,1]:
            for ver in [-1,0,1]:
                if not hor==ver==0 and (0<=x+hor<self.width and 0<=y+ver<self.height):
                    cont+=self.cell_state([(x+hor)%self.width,(y+ver)%self.height])
        return cont

    def alive_dead(self,coord):
        #for each cell, tells wether it must switch its state or not
        cell=self.pos_cell(coord)
        if not cell.state:
            if self.neighbors_state(cell.coord)==3:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        elif cell.state:
            if self.neighbors_state(cell.coord) in [2,3]:
                return True
            else:
                return False
#NB starting cells must be given as a list, not as a grid
def game_of_life(width,height,starting_cells):
    #the heart of the script
    test=[[Cell(i,j) for j in range(height)] for i in range(width)]
    world=Mondo(width,height,starting_cells)
    world.plotlib()
    for i in range(world.width):
        for j in range(world.height):
            if world.alive_dead([i,j]):
                test[i][j].turn_on()

    starting_cells=[test[i][j] for i in range(width) for j in range(height)]
    plt.pause(0.5)
    return game_of_life(width,height,starting_cells)


#Example of an oscillator:
#print game_of_life(10,10,[Cell(1,2,1),Cell(2,3,1),Cell(3,1,1),Cell(3,2,1),Cell(3,3,1)])

#Example of the Gosper gun:
gosper=[[Cell(i,j) for j in range(70)] for i in range(30)]
for i in range(len(gosper)):
    for j in range(len(gosper[0])):
        if [i,j] in [[1,26],[2,24],[2,26],[3,14],[3,15],[3,22],[3,23],[3,36],[3,37],[4,36],[4,37],[4,22],[4,23],[4,13],[4,17],[5,12],[5,18],[5,22],[5,23],[5,1],[5,2],[6,1],[6,2],[6,12],[6,16],[6,18],[6,19],[6,24],[6,26],[7,26],[7,18],[7,12],[8,13],[8,17],[9,14],[9,15]]:
            gosper[i][j].turn_on()
gosp=[gosper[i][j] for i in range(len(gosper)) for j in range(len(gosper[0])) if gosper[i][j].state]
print game_of_life(30,70,gosp)

#Mondo(30,70,gosp).plotlib()
#print Mondo(30,70,gosp)
```

I gave a look at the matplotlib.animation but maybe there's too much stuff for me to use just for a Uni assignment.

Is there some module I can use to print some simple animation? Should I try harder with matplotlib.pyplot, and if so, how can I adjust axes ratio and stuff?
SUrfing the questions I found the module graphics, may it be useful?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! Please note that questions asking for tool recommendations are generally frowned upon here. Can you rephrase your question to show what you've tried sofar and where you are stuck? For more info on this, have a look at [what type of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: You can check [this](https://gist.github.com/nicoguaro/2b7fe97005711932e8a3) implementation I did once.